# Force unseen PictureBox to load image

Tags: c#, picturebox

I have a form on which many PictureBoxes line up, not all of them are shown on the form at the same time (there's scrollbar on the form to reveal unseen PictureBoxes).  Their images location are internet URLs. I want to save those images locally right after each image is loaded, therefore I hook to the ContentLoaded Event of those PictureBoxes.

The problem is that the unseen PictureBoxes do not load images, and therefore their images cannot be saved, until the form is scrolled to make them visible. But I cannot expect user will scroll the whole content of the form all the times.

Is there a way to force unseen PictureBox to load its image?

Thanks.

EDIT:

Hello, DmitryG, may be the problem is that I have my PictureBoxes LoadAsync "loading images" before loading the true content. In your code, if you add

```
        pb.ImageLocation = "http://images.google.com.vn/intl/en_ALL/images/logos/images_logo_lg.gif";

        pb.LoadAsync();
```

in the loop before

```
        pb.ImageLocation ="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png";
        pb.LoadAsync();
```

then load the form, you will see 7 messageboxes only instead of 10. It is because 3 PictureBoxes are hidden.

Comment: Just use the Image property to assign a "waiting to load" image.  Use one from a resource.

Answer (score 2):

You can perform image loading despite of the picturebox visibility by calling the [PictureBox.LoadAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/221dw5x0.aspx) method. When the image loading will be completed the [PictureBox.LoadCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.loadcompleted.aspx) will be raised:

```
pictureBox1.LoadCompleted += pictureBox1_LoadCompleted;

pictureBox1.InitialImage = Image.FromFile(@"... path to waiting-to-load image ...");

pictureBox1.ImageLocation = <...path to image...>;
pictureBox1.LoadAsync(); // perform loading

void pictureBox1_LoadCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e) {
    // do something with loaded image
}
```

**Update:** sample code for auto-scroll panel and 5 pictureboxes.

```
panel1.AutoScroll = true;
panel1.Height = 1000;
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
    pb.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
    pb.Height = panel1.Height/2;
    pb.WaitOnLoad = false;
    pb.InitialImage = Image.FromFile("WaitingToLoad.gif");
    pb.ImageLocation = @"https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png";
    pb.LoadCompleted += pb_LoadCompleted;

    pb.Parent = panel1;
    pb.LoadAsync(); //<<<<<
}
//
void pb_LoadCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e) {
    MessageBox.Show("Load completed!");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for quick reply, but you misunderstood my question. My code is similar to yours (I set WaitOnLoad=false, with some modification to add the "loading image" while loading actual content). Using this code, I expect the PictureBox to load the image from its internet URL, despite of its visibility, but it does not.

Comment: @user2345529 This code works fine to me (I've place the picturebox onto invisible tab page and even set `pictureBox1.Visible=false` to ensure that the visibility does not affect image loading at all).

Comment: Hello, DmitryG, I have tested like this. I put 5 PictureBoxes in a Panel, resize the Panel to fit 2 only, and set the panel AutoScroll to true. Then I dynamically (in code) set the all PictureBoxes' URLs to an internet URL of an image. The result is that the three unseen PictureBoxes will not load their images until I scroll the panel to make them visible. The same if I set the pictureBox1.Visible=false, then turn on its Visble by a button. Do you set the PictureBox image location to an Internet URL, not a local path?

Comment: Yes, I'm using an web url for ImageLocation (`https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png`). I'll try to test your scenario a bit later and notify you on my results.

Comment: I've checked my code with autoscroll-panel a 5 pictureboxes - the pictureBox.LoadAsync() method calls make all 5 images loaded explicitly. See the updated answer.

Comment: Hello, DmitryG, your code works for me. I will take a close look to see what is the difference between mine and yours and post back later, thank you very much.

Comment: Hello, DmitryG, could you please take a look at my updated question?

Comment: I suggest you use the [PictureBox.InitialImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.initialimage.aspx) with predefined image(local). See my updated answer.